# AWSコンソールで誤ってロールを削除した場合の対処方法

Tags: aws, aws-iam

AWS管理画面にて誤ってロールを削除してしまい、cloudformationの管理がうまくいかなくなった場合、良い対処方法はないでしょうか。
ちなみに新たにロール作成する初期の設定を思だせず、どうすればよいか困っています。
方法あればご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

復元する方法はないでしょう。

誤って消さないように権限を適切に制御するか、ロールも含めてCloudFormationで作成することです。